# Creating An XLSX .rels from scratch .rels file not working properly?

Tags: excel, xml, xlsx

So right now i'm working on creating an xlsx from scratch. Ive decided to dive right into the zip and replicate it through code. I've literally just copied and pasted everything exactly the same just changed the data on the backend.

I've noticed a very weird bug that seems to break the xlsx file after repacking it as a zip.

when I wrote my .rels.xml file in the back end and open it up via Browser it seems to display .rels.xml as normal.

However After going back into the original .rels.xml file of the original xlsx it is displayed as plain text, and after copying the file to the folder theres no "Would you like to replace the file" prompt almost as if it was a completely different name. Lastly it seems copying this .rels.xml from the original over to my backend , the xlsx seems to want to actually open.

Any clues as to why this behavior occurs?

EDIT: Seems like the same thing happens to the workbook.xml in the xl/_rels directory. I really have no clue why it does this... i'm not sure if its just because of the odd naming senses or not...

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you want to achieve. Why are you not using a library that can work with the xlsx files? It is not a good idea to manipulate the xml unless you are absolutely sure what you are doing. Anyway if you still want to try use Notepad++ as the editor might change the xml encoding without warninig you. Also when you zip back use 7-zip and choose "store" or "normal-deflate" zip.

edit: I see now that you edit the xmls through code. So forget about notepad but keep an eye on the encoding

Comment: I figured it out. after opening it through the browser and seing the full path. It seems that even though Windows recognizes .rels as an XML type you can't append the .xml part to it. The Other workbook.xml needs a .rels extension after it too for it to work properly. Really strange but it fixed it. 

As to Why i'm not using a library I'm actually creating this in GML which no current library for XLSX format Exist... so i'd probably be the first to make a library for GMS2 x)